# Help Puzzling grow, you can... or just make a Riley

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix deceives people to make them believe
>
> My infix is the prefix of the perfect number by believe
>
> My suffix placed after my infix has been
> done many times on a concert
>
> My whole is what we all try do on this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we all try to

> **contribute**, which also fits the title.

My prefix deceives people to make them believe

> a **con**

My infix is the prefix of the perfect number by believe

> I know what is defined as perfect numbers, but I have no lead on what is *believed* to be *the* perfect number. But the **three** is laden with so many mystical meanings, why not perfection. The infix is just the **t**.
>  Alternatively, as *cpcodes* suggested, **tri** might be seen as infix, which is a prefix with the meaning of *three*, thus better fitting the puzzle text, with *trinity* being the relation to perfection.

My suffix placed after my infix has been done many times on a concert

> Bands often play cover versions under the term **tribute**, even for stuff that would better have stayed uncovered in this particular meaning of the word. But I digress. The suffix is **ribute** or, by *cpcodes* suggestion, **bute**, and has no meaning on its own in either case.

Comment: I think the infix might be "trinity" (a la holy trinity), which some sects of Christianity believe to be the three embodiments of the Creator, who is in turn believed to be perfect. It's a bit of a stretch I admit, but it fits the "by believe" part of the clue. I think the intent there was to use the word "belief" (which makes more grammatical sense) rather than "believes". Anyway, the prefix would then be "tri". Aside from that, I think you have it.

Comment: @cpcodes: I thought of that, but neither did I consider this to be a number in a proper sense of the word, nor did I see it related to perfection as a number. At least not more than the more general three, which is the same number anyway. A stretch, as you say. But given that it simply looks nicer in the prefix-infix-suffix-scheme, I think you're right and that's what Mr. Dead Sven intended. - I'll add it to the solution.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer good job! @cpcodes was spot on with the holy trinity part for the infix and yes it should have been belief as I stated in a comment of my question, my English is unfortunately not so good and I'm trying my best :p.